# How can I extract a dynamic length string from multiline string?

Tags: c#

I am using "nslookup" to get machine name from IP.

```
nslookup 1.2.3.4
```

Output is multiline and machine name's length dynamic chars. How can I extract "DynamicLengthString" from all output. All suggestions **IndexOf** and **Split**, but when I try to do like that, I was not a good solution for me. Any advice ?

```
Server:  volvo.toyota.opel.tata
Address:  5.6.7.8

Name:    DynamicLengthString.toyota.opel.tata
Address:  1.2.3.4
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried.

Comment: How do you identify a `DynamicLengthString`?

Comment: No identification, its machine name. I want to just extract that

Comment: `var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<=Name:)(.+?)(?=.toyota.opel.tata)");`  This was my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it the goold old c# way without regex.

```
string input = @"Server:  volvo.toyota.opel.tata
Address:  5.6.7.8

Name:    DynamicLengtdfdfhString.toyota.opel.tata
Address:  1.2.3.4";

string targetLineStart = "Name:";
string[] allLines = input.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string targetLine = String.Empty;
foreach (string line in allLines)
    if (line.StartsWith(targetLineStart))
    {
        targetLine = line;
    }

System.Console.WriteLine(targetLine);

string dynamicLengthString = targetLine.Remove(0, targetLineStart.Length).Split('.')[0].Trim();


System.Console.WriteLine("<<" + dynamicLengthString + ">>");
System.Console.ReadKey();
```

This extracts "DynamicLengtdfdfhString" from the given input, no matter where the Name-Line is and no matter what comes afterwards.
This is the console version to test & verify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        string Content = "Server:  volvo.toyota.opel.tata \rAddress:  5.6.7.8 \rName:    DynamicLengthString.toyota.opel.tata  \rAddress:  1.2.3.4";
        string Pattern = "(?<=DynamicLengthString)(?s)(.*$)";
        //string Pattern = @"/^Dy*$/";
        MatchCollection matchList = Regex.Matches(Content, Pattern);
         Console.WriteLine("Running");

        foreach(Match match in matchList)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no pattern, its coming from console output. Kinda BKI, SMI, EKFY etc.

Comment: try updated code. need simple alteration based on your Content

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your output is exactly like you put it.

```
string output = ExactlyAsInTheQuestion();

var fourthLine = output.Split(Environment.NewLine)[3];

var nameValue = fourthLine.Substring(9); //skips over "Name:    "

var firstPartBeforePeriod = nameValue.Split('.')[0];

//firstPartBeforePeriod should equal "DynamicLengthString"
```

Note that this is a barebones example:

- Either check all array indexes before you access them, or be prepared to catch `IndexOutOfRangeException`s.
- I've assumed that the four spaces between "Name:" and "DynamicLengthString" are four spaces. If they are a tab character, you'll need to adjust the `Substring(9)` method to `Substring(6)`.
- If "DynamicLengthString" is supposed to also have periods in its value, then my answer does not apply. You'll need to use a regex in that case.

Note: I'm aware that you dismissed `Split`:

> All suggestions IndexOf and Split, but when I try to do like that, I was not a good solution for me.

But based on only this description, it's impossible to know if the issue was in getting `Split` to work, or it actually being unusable for your situation.